# CRS conversion with epsg_operations.properties btw. EPSG:32041 and EPSG:3857

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

I try to correct the visualisation of EPSG:32041 on a Bing map. For that purpose, when i import the 32041 data i use a correction in geotools with epsg_operations.properties.

I debugged, which transformation is created when no entry for 32041,3857 is present in epsg_operations.properties and took that as a base which i than specified in epsg_operations.properties.

However, without changing any of the parameters in the transformation the data imported without an entry in epsg_operations.properties differs from data imported with entry in epsg_operations.properties.

I debugged and found out that the transformation in epsg_operations.properties is not used directly, but its further transformed. That happens in **`PropertyCoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory.createFromCoordinateReferenceSystemCodes(String, String, boolean)`** Small part of it here, `mt` is the transformation from properties file, `mt2` is the transformation used for CRS reprojection:

```
    // Create MathTransform from WKT
    MathTransform mt = null;
    try {
        mt = factories.getMathTransformFactory().createFromWKT(WKT);
    } catch (FactoryException e) {
        // Probably malformed WKT.
        LOGGER.warning("Error creating transformation: " + WKT);
        return null;
    }

    // Create the CRS definitions
    String s = this.authority.getIdentifiers().iterator().next().getCode();
    CoordinateReferenceSystem source = CRS.decode(s + ":" + sourceCRS);
    CoordinateReferenceSystem target = CRS.decode(s + ":" + targetCRS);

    // Need to create a derived MathTransform that will handle axis order and units
    // as defined in CRS. Had to cast to DefaultMathTransformFactory because
    // createBaseToDerived is not defined in MathTransformFactory interface (GeoAPI).
    DefaultMathTransformFactory mtf =
            (DefaultMathTransformFactory) factories.getMathTransformFactory();
    MathTransform mt2 = mtf.createBaseToDerived(source, mt, target.getCoordinateSystem());
```

DefaultMathTransformFactory.createBaseToDerived() sais, it expects a *"raw" transform without unit conversion or axis switch*.
Maby this is my problem? If yes, how do i get this raw transformation in WKT?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think we need to see the WKT input string, what you have in your epsg.prop file and what the output with and without it is

Comment: props file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5n23t71cb9culkd/epsg_operations.properties?dl=0
by the way, the other transformations 32067->3857, 26717->3857 i don't have this problem.

transformation without using props (data comes from gt-epsg-hsql ) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebhvs2xrx1gqms0/trans.txt?dl=0

The difference is in elt_0_0 and elt_1_1 values.